# Wrong index is chosen by Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, indexing, oracle10g

I have a problem in indexing in Oracle. Will try to explain my problem with an instance as follows.

I have a table TABLE1 with columns A,B,C,D
another table TABLE2 with columns A,B,C,E,F,H

I have created Indexes  for TABLE1

```
IX_1 A
IX_2 A,B
IX_3 A,C
IX_4 A,B,C
```

I have created Indexes  for TABLE1

```
IY_1 A,B,C
IY_2 A
```

when i gave query similar to this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1,TABLE2 T2
WHERE T1.A=T2.A
```

When i give Explain Plan i got its not getting  IX_1  nor  IY_2

Its taking IX_4  nor  IY_1

why this is not picking right index?

EDITED:

Can anyone help me to know difference between INDEX RANGE SCAN,INDEX UNIQUE SCAN, INDEX SKIP SCAN

I guess SKIP SCAN means when a column is skipped in Composite Index by Oracle

what about others i dont have idea!

Comment: There is not _right_ or _wrong_ when it comes to using indexes. Oracle choses the execution plan that is the most optimal according to it's cost calculation. Have you updated your database statistics lately? Furthermore, I don't understand why you have so many indexes. All queries that could benefit from IX_1, IX_2 or IY_2 can be executed with very similar cost and execution plan if IX_4 and IY_2 are used instead.

Comment: Thanks Codo. i didn't create these indexes. we are implementing on JAROSODS database. they have ample of indexes in it. i tried to resemble kind of my problem. Also i dont have access to change those indexes. just to use them

Comment: @Codo >> you mean to say we cant change cost calculation manually? also what do you mean by database statistics here?

Comment: For Oracle to calculate the cost of a query plan, it needs to know how many row a table has, how frequent certain values etc. This statistical data needs to be computed regularly with the DBMS_STATS package. Otherwise Oracle uses inefficient execution plans. And I don't understand why you would want to change cost calculation? What would that be good for? What's the purpose of your question anyway? Do you have a performance problem with the posted query?

Comment: Sorry Codo, I was little bit vague i guess in explaining my problem. Actually in my query i have used where clause exactly as in index. but that index was not picked it is picking some other index and does INDEX SKIP SCAN (Cost is too high) . But if i do as Florin Ghita suggested, cost is reduced alot. Sorry actually i meant to say i want to reduce cost not change cost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best benefit of indexes is that you can select **a few rows** from a table without scanning the entire table.
If you ask for too many rows(let's say 30% - depends of many things) the engine will prefer to scan the entire table for those rows. 
That's because reading a row using an index is gets an overhead : reading some index blocks, and after that reading table blocks.

In your case, in order to join tables T1 and T2, Oracle needs all the rows from those table. Reading(full) the index will be an unsefull operation, adding unnecesary cost.

**UPDATE**: A step forward: if you run:

```
SELECT T1.B, T2.B FROM TABLE1 T1,TABLE2 T2
WHERE T1.A=T2.A
```

Oracle probably will use the indexes(IX2, IY2), because it does not need to read anything from table, because the values T1.B, T2.B, **are** in indexes.

Comment: But can i know whats difference between INDEX RANGE SCAN,INDEX UNIQUE SCAN, INDEX SKIP SCAN

Comment: Yes Florin what you said is right!! i could get losts of COST differences by selecting selected columns in query. Thanks... Sorry if i'm wrong, why my cost changes if i add another column in **select query** that is not in index

Comment: at page 62 you can find explanations: http://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=oracle+database+concepts+11g+release+2+pdf&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fdocs%2Fcd%2FE11882_01%2Fserver.112%2Fe25789.pdf&ei=DG7KTtO-H6Sk4gT7t7Rl&usg=AFQjCNFC2IF4gfuwZuCviTf5XzbIw7FwvA&sig2=M1xI2YxRwb0KM8yuoYFRUQ

Comment: for the second question you can check the last sentence of my response: If the those values are in index, will not read them form table, so the cost is lesser.